# What is a measurable set $E \subset [0, 1]$ such that the closure of $E$ is $[0, 1]$ and $m(E) = \epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ and $m$ is Lebesgue measure. What is a measurable set $E \subset [0, 1]$ such that the closure of $E$ is $[0, 1]$ and $m(E) = \epsilon$?

Answer (score 8):

HINT: You can add $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ to any measurable subset of $[0,1]$ without changing its measure.